# I have kept @parallel=false at my feature level and scenarios are not executing parallel but all the feature files are executing parallel

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have kept @parallel=false at my feature level and scenarios are not executing parallel but all the feature files are executing parallel Is there any way we can stop executing feature files parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the number of threads to 1.